# Spotify Embed Width 100%

Tags: html, css

I looked everywhere but no joy, the embed code will not go 100% width and not sure why? I know on the embed link it's wider then what it showing me, so I know it should be possible.

This the code:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:elaina79:playlist:17AFix67QKFL33ZsZGmdNq" style="width:100%; height:480px;"
 frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And looks like...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgQpB.png

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the iframe dont need to use `style=""` to create style.. use `width` or `height`

```
Example: <iframe src="smthinghere" width="100%" height="100%"  style="width:100%; height:480px;" />
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: If I do it 100% 100% that works but it doesn't show the playlist just the player. The code you give's still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it states that the max width is `640px`. See [Player min/max sizes](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/#player-min-max-sizes).

Setting a `width` and `height` attribute with `100%` shows only the player and not the playlist. I don't think you have enough control over the embed to make it fully fluid.

Comment: I don't understand because this is over 640px https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:elaina79:playlist:17AFix67QKFL33ZsZGmdNq

Comment: They try to maintain a certain ratio. If you change the window height you will see it gets smaller/larger.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS you can do

```
    body{
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }


    iframe {
        height: 100%;
        width:96%; /* for small screen sizes */
    }
```

and you'll have the maximum allowed width for the iframe playlist and maximum height.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this script which I've seen elsewhere, which mostly resolved the issue for me:

```
function respondify(){
  $('iframe[src*="embed.spotify.com"]').each( function() {
    $(this).css('width',$(this).parent(1).width());
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  respondify();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  respondify();
});
```

However, at large widths, the `#outerWidgetContainer` didn't go full scale (stopped at 320px) until  I set the iframe to the largest widget dimensions:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:1271829250:playlist:39OSZ9YnShKKkuL0Yc1iMp" frameborder="0" width="640px" height="720px"></iframe>
```

This triggered the `#outerWidgetContainer` to size to `width:100%` and everything worked.  I also set `overflow:hidden` on my container so it wouldn't spill out.